# Layout of plot in Altair is not appearing to show conditional colours in time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I've got some data on admissions in long format about obesity-related hospital admissions - you can see the full dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6hu7g556pzcyfkhhp1s5l/sorted_data.csv?rlkey=n1tz0mzddkdinkt14rofjxlj1&dl=0

It looks like this..

```
    Region          Major region    Year    variable            quantity
0   County Durham   North East      2014    Total admissions    2240.0
1   Darlington      North East      2014    Total admissions    283.0
2   Gateshead       North East      2014    Total admissions    1229.0
3   Hartlepool      North East      2014    Total admissions    484.0
4   Middlesbrough   North East      2014    Total admissions    422.0
```

I've used altair to create a plot with two dropdowns

import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

```
# Create dropdown for Major region
major_region_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['Major region'].unique().tolist(), name="Major region: ")
major_region_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Major region'], bind=major_region_dropdown)

# Create dropdown for variable
variable_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['variable'].unique().tolist(), name="Category: ")
variable_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['variable'], bind=variable_dropdown)

color_encoding = alt.condition(
    major_region_selection | variable_selection,
    alt.value('red'),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

# Sort the data
sorted_data = melted_df.sort_values(by='Year')

# Main chart
main_chart = alt.Chart(sorted_data).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y='mean(quantity):Q',
    color=color_encoding,
    tooltip=["Major region", "Region", "mean(quantity):Q"]
).add_selection(
    major_region_selection
).transform_filter(
    major_region_selection
).add_selection(
    variable_selection
).transform_filter(
    variable_selection
).properties(
    width=450, 
    height=600,
    title="Region"
)
```

main_chart

It's supposed to be a time series chart which plots individual Regions over time with the encoding switching between lightgray to red if points on the line are selected. But it comes out like this. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can add a detail encoding like `detail=['variable','Region', 'Major region'],` see also https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encodings/channels.html#detail.